# Invalid Geojson when drawing multipolyline on the map

Tags: leaflet, geojson

I try to display multi line in the map but it return

> "Error: Invalid GeoJSON object"

Here is my code

```
        $.ajax({
            type:     "POST",
            url:      "server/drawPipe.php",
            data:     {pwa_code : pwa_code},
            success: function(data){

                data = JSON.stringify(data);

                var jsonLayer = L.geoJson().addTo(map_google);
                jsonLayer.addData(data);

            }
        });
```

Here is the result that returns from drawPipe.php (I validate this Geojson via http://geojsonlint.com/, the result is correct)

{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[101.146594802185,17.2898164508615],[101.146539827898,17.2895967362354],[101.146516345161,17.2894192118485],[101.146497648309,17.2893130415973],[101.14649430089,17.2892767147386],[101.146484934618,17.2892244862197],[101.146463647515,17.2891385623201],[101.146586602643,17.288998402757],[101.146623647723,17.288956177505],[101.146737097675,17.2888484892937],[101.146799533689,17.2887918684111],[101.146903317291,17.2886909399864],[101.146909938481,17.288506958459],[101.14690397303,17.2880796318353],[101.146901612993,17.2880256437337],[101.146881556,17.2875721572498],[101.146878504378,17.2874770222705],[101.146882907032,17.2873846465749],[101.146894138478,17.2871466305424],[101.146894140357,17.2871465403733],[101.146894143724,17.2871426616135],[101.146894464609,17.2867666924102],[101.146907865134,17.2864394148899],[101.146914075563,17.2862862756153],[101.14694128003,17.2857201294004],[101.14695643629,17.2852044468443],[101.14696340772,17.2848288760523],[101.146963060262,17.2847935089181],[101.146962287802,17.2847041908791],[101.146944918202,17.2845491549589],[101.146925868417,17.2844822172579],[101.146905152812,17.2844097450123],[101.146850132731,17.2842740108223],[101.146804593425,17.2841998886639],[101.146740705649,17.2841181071168],[101.146671904821,17.2840491304472],[101.146593174702,17.2839772567031],[101.146481452044,17.2838906765891],[101.146409944079,17.2838401398767],[101.146313904738,17.2837664899673],[101.14618180933,17.2836839380681]]]}

Could anyone suggest me please

Comment: Try not using `JSON.stringify`, just take that line out.

Comment: still get the same error

Comment: OK so second idea, do you know why the server returns a MultiLineString when the line has only one part? If you use a LineString (and take out one pair of square brackets), the geometry is still valid. Possibly that's an issue.

Comment: Why do you return your coordinates nested on the third level of an array? `coordinates[[ [x y],[x y] ]]`? Try removing one nesting level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GeoJSON is valid and renders fine, see http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/kogi/edit?html,output.

However, the use of jquery to fetch it is not. Make sure the request is returning JSON (hint: use `dataType: 'json'` in your [jquery ajax call](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)), and do not stringify the result Ion the contrary, run `JSON.parse()` if all you've got is a string). If you `console.log()` the geojson, it should look like a javascript object, not like a string.

Alernatively, ditch jQuery and use the [fetch API magical JSON-parsing capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json).

Comment: I found the answer!! 
Only add dataType : 'json' to ajax

$.ajax({
 type:     "POST",
 url:      "server/drawPipe.php",
 data: {pwa_code : pwa_code},
 dataType : 'json',
 success: function(data){
                 L.geoJson(data).addTo(map_google);
         }
});